# continuous call of Google Prediction API gives response 'Undefined'

Tags: google-api, google-api-ruby-client, google-prediction

In my application I have been calling google prediction API continuously for an array(size: 4000 aprox) of strings. I observed that after some api calls it starts giving response as `Undefined`, it continues for some time and then gives result fine. This is happening frequently.

I have checked their [api documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/predict/), but couldn't find any rate limit or any such restriction. Also there was no error logged in Google API manager dashboard.

Does anyone have any idea why its happening like that.