# continuous call for Google Prediction API gives response 'Undefined'

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client, google-prediction

In my application I have been calling google prediction API continuously for an array(size: 4000 aprox) of strings. I observed that after some api calls it gives response as `Undefined`, it continues for some api calls and then it gives response fine. But this is happening frequently.

I have checked their [api documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/predict/), but couldn't find any rate limit or any such restriction. Also there was no error logged in Google API manager dashboard.

Does anyone have any idea why its happening like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [continuous call of Google Prediction API gives response 'Undefined'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618071/continuous-call-of-google-prediction-api-gives-response-undefined)

Comment: There is no answer for that question.